# Issue with finding eigenvalues with smallest magnitude using eigs

Tags: julia, arpack

I have a large Hermitian sparse matrix, and I'd like to get a few of the eigenvalues with the smallest magnitude. I'm using the "eigs" function in Arpack however I get this error message:

> ZeroPivotException: factorization encountered one or more zero pivots. Consider switching to a pivoted LU factorization.

Does anyone know how to get around this error? Is it possible to add an argument to eigs to use pivoted LU factorization instead?

Comment: Please stop putting tag information in the title. The tagging system here works very well, and doesn't need any assistance. People who can answer this sort of question will be following the tags, not text in the title, and adding it redundantly to the title is simply clutter.

Comment: Thanks! Will take that into account in the future.

Comment: Also, it may be helpful if you gave a minimum working example (code that one can simply copy-paste and run).

Comment: What is the function call in question?